# JavaScript "takeown" function?

Tags: javascript, variables, dom, object

I wanted a quick simple way to "take ownership" of a JavaScript variable. For example:

```
function takeown( obj ) {
     obj = obj;
}

takeown( window.undefined );
```

So does this set `window.undefined` to `window.undefined`?

Sorry for the n00b question, but, I am a n00b at javascript.

Comment: ...What are you trying to do?

Comment: @PlatinumAzure Well, I _could_ do `window.undefined = window.undefined`, but I was wondering if what I posted would do the same thing. E.g. taking the parameter `obj` and setting it to itself. That way, when I call `takeown()` and pass `window.undefined` as a parameter, it "redefines" it.

Comment: you cant "overwrite" undefined anyway , undefined = "blop" , undefined will still be undefined.

Comment: No, undefined is easily overwritten. See http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/10-things-i-learned-from-the-jquery-source/ for Paul Irish's explanation.

Comment: @Kolink, no-op as in, it doesn't do anything?

Comment: not on modern browsers , didnt work on chrome for me

Comment: There is no point. obj = obj = "i know..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do nothing.  Javascript variables are references to objects in memory.  Your function takes a reference and points it to the same object that it was previously referencing, making it (as stated in the comments) a no-op.

If you want to redefine window.undefined, you can just do it by setting it to a new value (this is not advised).  Javascript doesn't protect its global variables in  the way you might expect.  Most of the built in values can be redefined, or augmented.

#### Update

Since you made it clear in your comment that what you actually want is a way to prevent a variable from being modified in the future, the best way to do that is with closures.

Closures are a way of taking advantage of javascript's handling of scope to simulate private variables and protect scope.  Specifically in this case, you can do something like this:

```
function createConstant(){

     var const = 3;
     return function(){
         return const;
     }
}
```

This will create a function that returns 3 immutably. So :

```
createConstant()
```

will always return 3.  (although technically you could redefine create constant to refer to a new function.  There is some level to which nothing can be done about this stuff.

Comment: Thats what I thought. Besides, wouldn't it be infinite? Then do absolutely nothing... Why don't you advise doing `var undf = undefined`?

Comment: There's no reason to do that over just using the global variable.  I'm not very clear on what you're trying to accomplish though.

Comment: `window.undefined = window.undefined` Simple. It doesn't even necessarily need to be "window.undefined", that's just what I thought of first, though. So, I could do `var x = "foo"; takeown( x ); // setting x to x infinitley, so that it's not rewritable`

Comment: ah I see. what you want is to prevent another piece of code from editing the variable.  For that you are going to want closures.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: Ok, I understand what you want now.  You should be using closures.

Comment: You mean IIFE? That's what I was working with before this, lol. I hate those things! But I guess that's what I will use.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is overriding a global variable (I don't understand why you are trying to do it), and this is done like this:

```
window.Counter = 'whatever';
// so
window.Counter // => 'whatever'
```

Your function assigns a variable to the same variable...no-op.
BUT, *undefined* is not writable since javascript 1.8.5 ([link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined)), any other global variable I think is writable.

Cheers,